# How to tell users of my class the valid values my constructor is expecting

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

This is a design question.

I am building a Console Memory Game as an assignment.
We were told that we should separate the UI from the business logic classes, so that when we will need to implement the game with a windows GUI, we can reuse the maximum possible.

In my design I have came to create the following classes: ConsoleUI, GameManager, MemoryGameBoard.

my question relates to the validity check of the MemoryGameBoard (Height, Width).
Being a MemoryGameBoard I have decided that it should check for legality by making sure that the number of elements is even (because we are dealing with pairs), and the GameManager should check for the rules that he imposes (being that the maximum row and column sizes must be 4/5/6 only).

The ConsoleUI is asking the user for this height and width. and should keep on re-asking until given valid data according to either GameManager or the MemoryGameBoard.

Where should the method that tests for validity of the height/width be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually try to avoid validity checks in a constructor.  I would use a `GameBoardBuilder` class with constructor `GameBoardBuilder(int width, int height)` and methods `IsValid()` and `MakeGameBoard()`.  So you would write:

```
while (true) {
   ... get input ...    
   var builder = new GameBoardBuilder(width, height);
   if (builder.IsValid()) break;
   ... report error ...
}
var gameBoard = builder.MakeGameBoard();
```

or using `GameManager` from UI:

```
while (true) {
    .... get input ...
    gameManager.SetBoardSize(width, height);
    if (gameManager.IsBoardValid()) break;
    ... report error ...
}
gameManager.StartGame();
```

where `GameManager` has methods:

```
public void SetBoardSize(int width, int height) {
    builder = new GameBoardBuilder(width, height);
}

public bool IsBoardValid() { return builder != null && builder.IsValid(); }

public void StartGame() {
    var gameBoard = builder.MakeGameBoard();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I like this idea but I have a question : Does this mean that ConsoleUI needs to create the GameBoard? I thought the gameboard creation should be encapsulated within the GameManager

Comment: Yes, you could call GameBoardBuilder from GameManager.  I was just showing a simple example of how it could be called.

Comment: I can't see how it will work, because if GameManager is the one creating and calling GameBoardBuilder, then ConsoleUI is not able to know if the given parameters for width and height are valid.

can you clarify more? thanks

Comment: Thank you, this solution makes a lot of sense, I ended up using a variation of it

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like

```
public void setHeight(int height)
{
    while(height%2!=0)
    {
       Ask user
    }
    class_instancevariable_height = height;
}

public void setWidth(int width)
{
same as height
}
```

Which you then call from the constructor

```
public MemoryGameBoard(int width, int height)
{
setWidth(width); setHeight(height);
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't comply with the requirements, as it suggests that the MemoryGameBoard ask the user itself. Being a business logic class, it may not interact with the user (because later down the road when we make the switch to WindowsUI, this solution would ask the user for input from the console (which doesn't exist))

Comment: @Jackl56 You could have an interface, `IUserInterface`, from which `ConsoleUI` inherits from, and supply an instance of `ConsoleUI` to the `MemoryGameBoard` class. Now the business logic can interact with the user be him on a `ConsoleUI` or an `WindowsUI`, via the interface. This is not my preferred approach, though, because it introduces a subtle coupling between the application layers. I would recommend `setHeight` and `setWidth` to return some sort of "error code" to indicate if the operation was successful or not, and then re-ask the user based on this. Similar to .Net with its `TryParse`.

Comment: @NothingsImpossible I had considered going with something like that, but the problem in that case would be that both ConsoleUI and WindowsUI would need to have the same interface (methods). ie AskUserForBoardHeight(); for the ConsoleUI that's not a problem, WriteLine() followed by ReadLine(), but how would WindowsUI implement this? InputBox() and forward it along would be enforcing the way the ConsoleUI interacts with the user, to WindowsUI which is not native. is that what you mean by the subtle coupling?

Comment: @Jackl56 what I mean by subtle coupling is that the business layer will depend on a user interface layer to work, it cannot work independently anymore. If you want to use it standalone, for example to do unit testing, you will have to build "dummy" classes for it to work, while if you use the return-code approach this isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separating the validation logic from the constructor. In the constructor, you should enforce validation to prevent constructing an invalid object (which makes the rest of the code simpler to write).

Here's an example:

```
class GameBoard
{
    public static bool IsValid(int width, int height, out List<string> errorMessages)
    {
        // validation logic here, e. g.
        errorMessages = new List<string>();
        if (width < 1) { errorMessages.Add("width must be a positive number");

        return errorMessages.Count == 0;   
    }

    public GameBoard(int width, int height)
    {
        var errorMessages;
        var isValid = IsValid(width, height, out errorMessages);
        // fail hard if given invalid input here
        Throw<ArgumentException>.If(
            !isValid, 
            string.Join(", ", errorMessages ?? new List<string>())
        );

        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;
    }
}

// in the gui code

// read input
List<sting> errorMessages;
while (!IsValid(width, height, out errorMessages))
{
    // display errorMessages
    // read input
}
```

`Throw.If` is from http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-one/.

Comment: So, I understand from your solution that we absolutely must not create a corrupted object - agreed. and because this is a penalty to performance, we would also allow the user to check before-hand - agreed. The problem I see with this solution is that the user of my class would have to look in the documentation to know about this function (and we know that most people don't) and because it's static I can't use it with polymorphism, adding a new type of GameBoard. any thought?